# About 'This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.'

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I use spring boot 3.0.3, gradle ver and thymeleaf and put html file into templates/board and then

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Jan 18 14:26:18 KST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No static resource board/boardLista.
org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource board/boardLista.

error has occurred.

controller is

```
@Controller
public class BoardController {

  @Autowired
  BoardService boardService;

  @GetMapping("/board/boardList")
  public ModelAndView openBoardList() throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("board/boardList");
    List<BoardDto> list = boardService.selectBoardList();
    mv.addObject("list",list);

    return mv;
  }
}
```

setting thymeleaf in application.properties

```
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true

spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/

spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html

spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5

spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8

spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html

spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

---

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'

dependency is set in gradle.build too.

xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" is in html file and

I tried re-run Spring Boot application and also clean but I couldn't solve this issue.

Comment: unless you want to change your error pages the fallback is ok, don't stress it too much

Comment: The index page can be accessed, but other URLs such as /board/boardList cannot be accessed.

Comment: Isn't the problem that you added each extra a at the end of the URL ? "board/boardLista"

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've solved. it was problem of path of controller. (I didn't know controller file should be same package with others)